# How to ensure a numeric matrix is retrieved from R

Tags: python, rpy2

Within a local conversion context established with the `default_converter` and `pandas2ri.converter` local converters, I am obtaining a `rpy2.robjects.vectors.BoolMatrix` object (assigned to a variable `res`):

```py
<rpy2.robjects.vectors.BoolMatrix object at 0x7fa48d531040> [RTYPES.LGLSXP]
R classes: ('matrix', 'array')
[NA, NA, NA]
```

I need to build a pandas dataframe from this object.  However, the conversion gives:

```py
pd.DataFrame(res)
            0
0 -2147483648
1 -2147483648
2 -2147483648
```

How can I ensure this kind of matrix is converted to `nan` values?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a conversion buglet on the rpy2 side. The recommended way to proceed is to 1) open an issue on the rpy2 tracker on Github and 2) have the following workaround until it is fixed:

```
import math
import rpy2.robjects as ro

# Let dataf_pd be the pandas DataFrame resulting from the conversion from
# an R data.frame and "x" be the name of the column of booleans with NAs.
dataf_pd.loc[dataf_pd.x == ro.NA_Logical] = math.nan
```